# All Global Actions not Showing up in Community Builder Button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community-builder

I've created some global actions that I'd like to add to my community but for some reason they aren't being listed as options in the properties pane of the create record button. The help text says it lists all global actions.

[image]

[image]

[image]

There are way more global actions that exist than are being listed and any I create aren't showing up. What am I missing?

Comment: I should add that if I do the same thing in my developer organization it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well that was silly of me - the reason is record types. Community builder will not show you any global actions for record types that are not enabled for your profile. This includes the standard System Administrator profile. If you run into this issue go to your profile and add the record type of the global action and your problem will be solved